# How can I get the file timestamp to add to Last-Modified in nginx config?

Tags: nginx, configuration

I am using nginx.

I have a few static files. When one of these files is modified, I would like to get that information. I was hoping to use the `Last-Modified` header like this.

```
add_header Last-Modified $time_stamp_of_uri
```

or something like that. But I cannot find a variable for `$time_stamp_of_uri`

I already looked at this list. http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html

Comment: what about using  $time_iso8601 ? sample format :
2014-12-15T15:30:02-05:00

Comment: $time_iso8601 gives the current timestamp of the server. What is the attribute for file time stamp?

Answer (score 2):

If you serve files from local disk, you should not worry about `Last-Modified` header - nginx will add it automatically.

If you are proxying files from backend - it's a backend business to generate all necessary headers. Not nginx, definitely.

If you have strange demand to process  `Last-Modified` headers returned by backend - you should use built-in perl or lua (available as third-part module) for such transformation.

Comment: We are looking for timestamp of dynamically created file (ruby on rails).

Comment: You can create the file on local filesystem and then set "X-Accel-Redirect" header pointing to the URI will serve the file from local filesystem. In this case nginx will add "Last-Modified" header himself based on file mtime value.

Comment: Another variant - create file and then issue external redirect to its URI.

Comment: The perl module is not built in to NGINX.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html